# how to subtract two columns using Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Inventory management project

i have **`TransactionUpdate`** table with columns `TransactionUpdatId`,`OrderNumber`,`BalanceAmount`,`OrderTotalAmt`,`OrderType`,`LastUpdateDate`

Now in my scene, i am using repeater to load data. in repeater, if `OrderType` is `Opening Balance` then Balance Amount of customer should be output. And is `OrderType` is `Send Booking` then BalanceAmount should be deducted as `BalanceAmount` - `OrderTotalAmt`. I want to write this in repeater using **Eval**

i have tried following:

```
<%#(Eval("OrderType").ToString() == ("Opening Balance") ? "BalancAmount" :
                                       (Eval("OrderType").ToString() == "Send Booking") ?  Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("BalanceAmount")) - Convert.toDecimal(Eval("OrderTotalAmt")%>
```

But this says syntax error near `:`. This is obvious but i dont know where to put it and how

Comment: You should replace It for a code behind function that that requires as parameter what you need to substract.

Comment: As mentioned above.. U should have repeater's data bound event.. And then dynamically calculate the property and bind individual columns' value

Comment: I am giving `CustomerId` as Parameter. i only want to show data of this table.using repeater and `BalanceAmount` should be like in this manner. Any change in `Eval` syntax??

Comment: There should not be an end parenthesis before the first question mark. But heed the advice of others, and move this to either a function or modify the dataset before binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a code behind function call from the ASPX page from within the repeater then the Eval() method can be used in that method.  This can make the code much easier to read when the statement is complicated like yours.

Note that I am not sure I got your logic correct, but you can get the idea and clean that up.

In the repeater:

```
  <%# BalanceCalc() %>
```

Code behind method

```
    protected string BalanceCalc()
    {
        switch (Eval("OrderType").ToString())
        {
            case "Opening Balance":
                return "BalancAmount";
            case "Send Booking":
                return Convert.ToString(Eval("BalanceAmount"));
            default:
                return (Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("BalanceAmount")) - Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("OrderTotalAmt"))).ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir, The ASPX page is just a class.  One that inherits from the code behind.  The Eval method is from an ancestor to the PageBase class (specifically, the TemplateControl).  It works just fine in the code behind.

Comment: I think it's suppose to be `DataBinder.Eval`

Answer (score 1):

Looking in Notepad++ , you Had some missing `(` , typos, and missing `else :`
Here is the fixed version :

```
<%# (Eval("OrderType").ToString() == "Opening Balance") ? "BalancAmount" :
                                       ((Eval("OrderType").ToString() == "Send Booking") ?  (Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("BalanceAmount")) - Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("OrderTotalAmt"))) : "It's no SendBooking")%>
```

Comment: is it ok to write "it's notSending" in last? can put simply " " ??

Comment: You can put `""`. I just wrote that so you can see that you've missed the `else (:)` part.